# How Schema RDD can help in inserting data into my Database in Apache Spark

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

How Schema RDD can help in persist data into any Database in Apache Spark and also it is available in new version1.4.1 or not?

Comment: SchemaRDD is renamed to DataFrame in the new version.

Comment: DataFrame frame = sqlContext.createDataFrame(clientRDD, UserDetailsSql.class);

frame.insertIntoJDBC(MYSQL_CONNECTION_URL, "users1", true);

I am able to persist data through these line of code. but  InsertIntoJDBC method is deprecated. 

Please help me to find out which new version method will be able to do same task.\

Comment: Finally working with this code.

UserDetailsSql dataObject1 = new UserDetailsSql("Avnish");
  List<UserDetailsSql> ObjectList = new ArrayList<UserDetailsSql>();
  ObjectList.add(dataObject1);

  JavaRDD<UserDetailsSql> clientRDD = ctx.parallelize(ObjectList);

  DataFrame frame = sqlContext.createDataFrame(clientRDD, UserDetailsSql.class);
  
  DataFrameWriter dfw = new DataFrameWriter(frame);
  
  dfw.mode(SaveMode.Append).jdbc(MYSQL_CONNECTION_URL, "TableName", new Properties());

Answer (score 1):

Convert your RDD to DataFrame and write into Database,

```
val df = myrdd.toDF()

df.write.jdbc(…)
```

I ran into same spot and referred below link,
http://www.sparkexpert.com/2015/04/17/save-apache-spark-dataframe-to-database/

Answer (score 0):

Whatever is your database, use it's api as you use in simple java, scala or python and perform foreach transformation to the schema RDD, you can't insert the schema RDD automatically to your database, you have to do mapping in spark.

Comment: Can you please give an example so that i can understand.